# BISON encode/decode middleware for socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, middleware

Is there any way to tamper with the data that socket.io sends just before it is sent/received? I was thinking about something like an express middleware.
So that I could encode data after the normal .emit() method is called and before socket.on(...) is called.

In express I would imagine it to look somewhat like this to BISON decode all incoming request:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.body = BISON.decode(req.body);
    next();
});
```

Now how could that be done with socket.io in a way that requests being sent also get encoded automatically?

I know that socket.io supports middlewares in a similar form to express, but that is only for the actual http request that socket.io sends to create the websocket connection...

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    //...
    next();
});
```

so I doubt that this would be of any help here..

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept (and change) data by listening for `packet` events, and similarly use the `flush` event to intercept outgoing messages:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  socket.conn.on('packet', function(packet) {
    ...change `packet.data` here...
  });
  socket.conn.on('flush', function(packets) { // array of packets
    ...
  });
  next();
});
```

But to be honest, I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how `packet.data` is encoded, so I can't provide a full example.

**EDIT**: `socket.io-parser` has [`decodeString()`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-parser/blob/cec8d65e75a689a6a7c9e9f8a0d3fe8d957a40a1/index.js#L274) which is used to parse the payload. Sadly, it's not exported (and the methods that *are* exported are all async, which doesn't combine well with event handlers).

Comment: Very interesting. So I basically have to fork it or somehow extract that particular function. Hm... It feels kind of hacky. Are you sure there is no other way to do this?

Comment: I agree it feels hacky, but I haven't been able to find an alternative (which doesn't mean there aren't any, of course :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the client side btw. Any idea for that?

Comment: `client.io.on('packet', ...)` works, but there doesn't seem to be a `flush` equivalent :-(

Comment: I just read that there should be a `decoded` event: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol#parserdecoder Could we somehow intercept that one?

Comment: It doesn't look like the parser is accessible.

Comment: I had a really crazy idea last night: http://pastebin.com/apjGZsUa I'm not sure if this possible. So I would really like to know what you think about this.

Comment: That should work (provided that you use `originalOn` and not call `io.on` recursively ;-). I'm not too familiar with BISON so I don't know if it will handle non-BISON messages properly, so you probably want to add some error handling as well.

Comment: Awesome! Well, I'm planning to do the same thing on the client side, so data should always be BISON encoded.

Comment: Any idea how I could override the emit function of all rooms? E.g. `io.sockets.in('test-channel').emit('msg',{'test':123})`

Comment: Hmm not sure, I think you need to dive into the `socket.io` (or possibily `engine.io`) code to see how those are handled. I think that eventually it will call a generic "emit" function that might be a good candidate to monkeypatch.